# cordova build android failed where Android Studio is buiilding app

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm developing React app on Cordova, when I try to run

> cordova build android

is failing with following error message,

And the Error pointing out line is in build.gradle --> "apply plugin: 'com.android.application'"

I tried all ways, but unable to fix this error, please help.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my classpath in platforms/android/build.gradle file

```
dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2' }
```

Is this wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I think problem in your classpath.

Comment: Please include a lot more to explain why you think that is, how can it be addressed. For short interjection such as this, try to use comments instead!

Comment: Here is my classpath in platforms/android/build.gradle file

dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2' }
Is this wrong?